# How to use packaged modules in a non-node JS environment?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, spidermonkey

With the exception of node API usage (`fs`, `http`, `net`...), vanilla js remains executable on any engine. Simple functionality can be relatively easily "plucked" from a packaged module (provided the licensing terms are met), but this gets messy for larger modules.

Is there a straightforward/less-frowned-upon way to use a module in an arbitrary environment? Ideally such a *npm2notnpm* bridge would be able to interface with the complete module as forked, there is also no expectation to have it work in 100% cases :)

**Why?..** the CMS engine we have to work with can execute arbitrary javascript using Spidermonkey engine (on the server); unfortunately that's the only way to build anything functional on the platform. I'd like to be able to leverage available packages as much as possible ([`cheerio`](https://github.com/MatthewMueller/cheerio) on the wishlist) rather than re-inventing the wheel or copy-pasting code without context.

Comment: it's a pretty standard pattern already, just re-define exports and module before you eval each package and harvest the objects after you eval. should work 100% with normal commonJS modules...

Comment: How much overlap between the Spidermonkey engine and NodeJS is there? If it's a module that's generic and not using NodeJS code, there's a chance it's available elsewhere, like maybe as a bower module. But, it's not clear what kind of code you'd want to use, given the limitations you're already aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Require.js](http://requirejs.org/) to load many Common.js packaged modules. Or you could define exports = window and pass that to the module to get access to the module.

http://requirejs.org/docs/commonjs.html

Comment: Yes. I misunderstood the problem to be moving node modules to spidermonkey-based browsers. If he's able to execute code under spidermonkey standalone I'd need to know what they're using to do that before recommending a potential solution (Rhino?)